# KSQLDB randomly stops working with Kafka cluster - "Error sending fetch request" and blocked thread warnings

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

We are running a KSQLDB with two nodes, which connects to a 16-node Kafka cluster. After about a week, the KSQLDB randomly stops working, and we are unable to use the KSQL CLI. The server status becomes "unknown," and we cannot perform queries. After we restart it, it runs for about a week and then the problem occurs again.

We see the following error messages in the client logs repeatedly:

```
[2023-02-24 10:00:16,939] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat_] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1589599502, epoch=1) to node 3: (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler:602)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
[2023-02-24 10:00:16,939] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat_] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1099103137, epoch=1) to node 6: (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler:602)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
[2023-02-24 10:00:16,940] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat_] Disconnecting from node 4 due to request timeout. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:797)
[2023-02-24 10:00:16,940] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat_] Cancelled in-flight FETCH request with correlation id 4703574 due to node 4 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 33672ms, elapsed time since send: 33672ms, request timeout: 30000ms) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:341)
[2023-02-24 10:00:16,940] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat_] Disconnecting from node 6 due to request timeout. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:797)
[2023-02-24 10:00:16,940] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat_] Cancelled in-flight FETCH request with correlation id 4703575 due to node 6 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 33666ms, elapsed time since send: 33666ms, request timeout: 30000ms) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:341)
[2023-02-24 10:00:16,940] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=_confluent-ksql-ksqldb_uat_] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1228760502, epoch=1) to node 4
```

And we can also see the following log in our /var/log/messages:

```
"Feb 24 08:10:46 server01 ksql-server-start[1427851]: Feb 24, 2023 8:10:46 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
Feb 24 08:10:46 server01 ksql-server-start[1427851]: WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-3,5,main]=Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-3,5,main] has been blocked for 4552 ms, time limit is 2000 ms
Feb 24 08:10:46 server01 ksql-server-start[1427851]: Feb 24, 2023 8:10:46 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
Feb 24 08:10:46 server01 ksql-server-start[1427851]: WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main]=Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 4552 ms, time limit is 2000 ms"
```

Here's our ksql-server.properties:

```
listeners=https://ksqldbuat:8088
ksql.internal.listener=https://ksqldbuat:8088

ssl.truststore.location=/etc/security/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=xxxxxxxx
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/security/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=xxxxx
ssl.key.password=xxxxxx

#------ BASIC AUTH--------
authentication.method=BASIC
authentication.roles=admin
authentication.realm=KsqlServer-Props


# Automatically create the processing log topic if it does not already exist:
ksql.logging.processing.topic.auto.create=true

# Automatically create a stream within KSQL for the processing log:
ksql.logging.processing.stream.auto.create=true


#------ Kafka -------

# The set of Kafka brokers to bootstrap Kafka cluster information from:
bootstrap.servers=broker1:9092...broker2:9092
ksql.service.id=ksqldb_uat_
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true serviceName="kafka" keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/_ksqldb_uat3.keytab" principal="_ksqldb_uat3@DOMAIN";
# Enable snappy compression for the Kafka producers
compression.type=lz4


ksql.internal.ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2


#------ Schema Registry -------

ksql.schema.registry.url=https://schemareg:8081, https://schemareg:8081
ksql.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/security/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ksql.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password=xxxxxxxx

#HA
ksql.internal.topic.replicas=4
ksql.internal.topic.min.insync.replicas=1
ksql.logging.processing.topic.replication.factor=4
ksql.logging.processing.topic.partitions=6
ksql.streams.num.standby.replicas=1
ksql.streams.replication.factor=4
ksql.streams.producer.acks=all
ksql.streams.topic.min.insync.replicas=1
ksql.query.pull.enable.standby.reads=true
ksql.heartbeat.enable=true
ksql.lag.reporting.enable=false

# Because of OOM
ksql.streams.rocksdb.config.setter=io.confluent.ksql.rocksdb.KsqlBoundedMemoryRocksDBConfigSetter
ksql.plugins.rocksdb.cache.size=4294967296
ksql.plugins.rocksdb.total.memory=4294967296
ksql.plugins.rocksdb.write.buffer.cache.use=true
ksql.plugins.rocksdb.num.background.threads=4
```

-Xms16G -Xmx16G

OS: RHEL 8.6

ksqlDB version: 0.28.2